# How to show two dates next to each other?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the SLQ below to select one date, but I want to see two dates next to each other.  How can I do that?

```
Delete From Variance_Analysis

INSERT INTO Variance_Analysis
SELECT PIDs.Product_Group,
      PIDs.PID,
      PIDs.PID_Name,
      SUM(MaturityValue) Current_Balance,
      AsOfDate as Current_Date
FROM [TBL_PIDs] AS PIDs INNER JOIN RAW_DATA_HIST AS RawData
    ON PIDs.PID = RawData.PID
Where AsOfDate = '2017-10-31'
GROUP BY Product_Group,
      PIDs.PID,
      PIDs.PID_Name,
      AsOfDate
```

As you can tell, I clear the table, and then insert some IDs and one date (while summing account balances).  I need to get another date and sum the respective balances.  Then, I want to find the absolute difference and relative difference, split out into 3 fields.  I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
-- Step1:
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    Product_Group varchar(255),
    PID varchar(10),
    PID_Name varchar(255),
    maturityValue decimal(18,2),
    AsofDate date,
    Portfolio varchar(255) 
);


-- Step2:
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Invt','I.B.7','Investments',1258.69,'9/29/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Asse','A.Q.7','Assets',1263.28,'9/29/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Forx','X.S.7','Foreign_Exchange',1267.89,'9/29/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Forx','X.S.7','Foreign_Exchange',1272.51,'9/29/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Forx','X.S.7','Foreign_Exchange',1277.15,'9/29/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Govt','G.G.7','Government',1281.81,'9/29/2017','Passing')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Govt','G.G.7','Government',1286.48,'9/29/2017','Passing')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Invt','I.S.7','Investments',1359.3852,'10/31/2017','Passing')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Asse','I.S.7','Assets',1364.3424,'10/31/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Forx','I.S.7','Foreign_Exchange',1331.2845,'10/31/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Forx','I.S.7','Foreign_Exchange',1336.1355,'10/31/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Forx','I.S.7','Foreign_Exchange',1341.0075,'10/31/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Govt','I.S.7','Government',1435.6272,'10/31/2017','Holding')
INSERT INTO test_table (Product_Group,PID,PID_Name,maturityValue,AsofDate,Portfolio)
VALUES ('Govt','I.S.7','Government',1518.0464,'10/31/2017','Passing')
```

Before:

```
Product_Group   PID PID_Name    maturityValue   AsofDate    Portfolio
Invt    I.B.7   Investments 1258.69 9/29/2017   Holding
Asst    A.Q.7   Assets  1263.28 9/29/2017   Holding
Forx    X.S.7   Foreign_Exchange    1267.89 9/29/2017   Holding
Forx    X.S.7   Foreign_Exchange    1272.51 9/29/2017   Holding
Forx    X.S.7   Foreign_Exchange    1277.15 9/29/2017   Holding
Govt    G.G.7   Government  1281.81 9/29/2017   Passing
Govt    G.G.7   Government  1286.48 9/29/2017   Passing
Invt    I.B.7   Investments 1359.3852   10/31/2017  Passing
Asst    A.Q.7   Assets  1364.3424   10/31/2017  Holding
Forx    X.S.7   Foreign_Exchange    1331.2845   10/31/2017  Holding
Forx    X.S.7   Foreign_Exchange    1336.1355   10/31/2017  Holding
Forx    X.S.7   Foreign_Exchange    1341.0075   10/31/2017  Holding
Govt    G.G.7   Government  1435.6272   10/31/2017  Holding
Govt    G.G.7   Government  1518.0464   10/31/2017  Passing
```

After:

[image]

Comment: Images aren't helpful for T-SQL questions (especially when all they conain are column heading and no data). Instead, please can you post your DDL and Sample Data, along with the expected output you want to achieve. At a guess, however, you'll likely going to need to use a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()`. Then `LEFT JOIN` one row onto the next/previous, based on the value of your Row Numbering. If you were using SQL Server 2012+, then you'd be able to use `LEAD`/`LAG`.

Comment: You need to start by providing some details. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
Delete From Variance_Analysis

INSERT INTO Variance_Analysis
SELECT   PIDs.Product_Group,
         PIDs.PID,
        PIDs.PID_Name,
         SUM(CASE WHEN AsOfDate = '2017-10-31' THEN MaturityValue ELSE 0 END) AS Current_Balance,
         SUM(CASE WHEN AsOfDate = '2017-09-29' THEN MaturityValue ELSE 0 END) AS Prior_Balance
FROM [TBL_PIDs] AS PIDs INNER JOIN TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST AS RawData
    ON PIDs.PID = RawData.PID
GROUP BY PIDs.Product_Group,
         PIDs.PID,
        PIDs.PID_Name
```